# How I go on a next line when the layout ends in android studio?

Tags: java, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

Currently I have a view that look like this:
[image]

I have implemented to insert the view programmatically in a horizontally-oriented LinearLayout. And I don't want my last view item to be displayed like that at the end. I want the it to be shown in the next row instead.

And this is my [xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lf0k.png):

```xml
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout0">
</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried `FlowLayout` and `GridLayout`, but both of them seem do not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:orientation="vertical"` within linearlayout to get elements in different lines.

You need to use **Nested LinearLayout** to do that, You can try adding five elements in Linearlayout that has **Horizontal orientation** and then create multiple layout like this and add it in Layout which has **Vertical orientation**.